# Javascript keypress/down/up events firing order

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard

Consider this simple code:

```
document.addEventListener( 'keypress', function() { console.log( 'press' ); } );
document.addEventListener( 'keydown',  function() { console.log( 'down' );  } );
document.addEventListener( 'keyup',    function() { console.log( 'up' );    } );
```

I tried it on both **Safari 9** and **FF 51** and the order the events fire is always:

`down` -> `press` -> `up`

This makes perfect sense (at least for me).

**My question is:**

Is this standard behaviour or some browsers (maybe older ones like IE8) trigger key events in a different order?

More specifically I'm interested to know if some browsers fires `press` **before** `down`.

Comment: What would make you think that the order could be anything other than: down, press, up?

Comment: Weird behaviour of a given browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as long as order is concern, yes all browser will execute same order... IE8 will not support addListner event so no question for order there.. but IE9 and IE9+ will execute same order.

Comment: well I've tested it on IE 8 to IE Edge, Chrome 10, FF 10, Safari 6 all behave same.. except IE that log console "EventListener not supported"